# ".objc_class_name_CUIFramework",referenced from:

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm working with developing an application for iPhone in Objective-C

Can anyone tel me how to solve this error:

```
".obj_class_name_CUIFramework", referenced from:
collect2:ld returned 1 exit status
literal-pointer@_OBJC@_cls_refs@CUIFramework in MF_CoreAppDelegate.o
symbol(s) not found
```

I tried to compile my code, i don't have idea for what this error is related to. Please help.what could be the problem?

i've added Foundation framework and UIKit framework

Answer (score 1):

Your code's well-formed, so compiles just fine. When the linker tries to link your application to the frameworks you use, it finds that you reference a framework that's not been imported to your application.

It looks like your code is using a class CUIFramework, but that you haven't added the appropriate framework to your project.

Comment: i've pasted the exact error which i'm getting. after "referenced from:" its left blank saying line location tool:0